# Different results, using same data and method(?), when using WordMat and R

Tags: r, function, equation-solving

I am interested to reproduce results calculated by the GNU plugin to MS Word [WordMat](http://www.eduap.com/wordmat/) in R, but I can't get them to arrive at similar results (I am not looking for identical, but simply similar).

I have some *y* and *x* values and a power function, *y = bx^a*

Using the following data,

```
x <- c(15,31,37,44,51,59)
y <- c(126,71,61,53,47,42)
```

I get a = -0.8051 and b = 1117.7472 in WordMat, but a = -0.8026 and B = 1108.2533 in R, slightly different values.

Am I using the `nls` function in some wrong way or is there a better (more transparent) way to calculate it in R?

Data and R code,

```
# x <- c(15,31,37,44,51,59)
# y <- c(126,71,61,53,47,42)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
moD <- nls(y~a*x^b, df, start = list(a = 1,b=1))
summary(moD)

Formula: y ~ a * x^b

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a  1.108e+03  1.298e+01   85.35 1.13e-07 ***
b -8.026e-01  3.626e-03 -221.36 2.50e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3296 on 4 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 19 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.813e-06
```

Comment: Well, mean abs. errors are: MAE_WordMat = 0.218, MAE_R = 0.195, so clearly R is doing better.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. How did you obtain the Mean absolute error (MAE) from WordMat and from R? Could you possible provide a reference that can help me convince my teacher that R is doing better and WordMat is not?

Comment: Just calculated `y_WordMat` and `y_R` and compared with `y`, it just showed that both are close, but R is closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like WordMat is estimating the parameters of `y=b*x^a` by doing the log-log regression rather than by solving the nonlinear least-squares problem:

```
> x <- c(15,31,37,44,51,59)
> y <- c(126,71,61,53,47,42)
> 
> (m1 <- lm(log(y)~log(x)))

Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ log(x))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       log(x)  
     7.0191      -0.8051  
> exp(coef(m1)[1])
(Intercept) 
   1117.747
```

To explain what's going on here a little bit more: if `y=b*x^a`, taking the log on both sides gives `log(y)=log(b)+a*log(x)`, which has the form of a linear regression (`lm()` in R).  However, log-transforming also affects the variance of the errors (which are implicitly included on the right-hand side of the question), meaning that you're actually solving a different problem.  Which is correct depends on exactly how you state the problem.  [This question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61747/linear-vs-nonlinear-regression) gives more details.

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful!

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: I appreciate you educate me about SO culture, I guess that's not a direct  "thank you." I apologize for not _check-mark to accept_ your answer. I was too focused to rewarding you the bounty.